# Hyperlinking in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am hyperlinking a spreadsheet with dates, numbers and text - it's a living document and the "source of truth" will be added to throughout the course of time. I am looking to have all blank hyperlinked fields to show blank and all hyperlinked filled in cells to show appropriately ie whole number or date...but when I hyperlink blank cells I get a false date of 01/0/1900 and if I reformat each of those cells with 0;0;;@ it will show blank however, if I add a date in the "source of truth" that cell will reflect a whole number.

How do I get blank cells to show blank and still be hyperlinked so that when the source of truth is populated, the hyperlinked sheet is populated correctly?

Comment: Are you using the embedded hyperlink feature or the `=HYPERLINK` function?

Comment: =HYPERLINK Function

Answer (score 0):

Use `m/d/yyyy;;;@`. It formats positive numbers as a date, negative numbers and zero as blank, and text as text.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68